# How to solve the `Error in calling method showPipe, because: Fail to connect to any ConfigNode` in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I use `show pipe` command in Apache IoTDB Version 1.2.1, an errror was informed: `Msg: 305: Error in calling method showPipe, because: Fail to connect to any ConfigNode. Please check status of ConfigNodes or logs of connected DataNode.` How to solve this error reported?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a problem in Apache IoTDB Version 1.2.1. You can try to upgrade to Version 1.2.2, where the function of `pipe` should be better optimized.